# How to wrap Javascript function within function expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, method-modifier

I would like to add a wrapper function to one of my functions to show extra information.

Below is my wrapper function:

```
var wrap =  function(functionToWarp, before) {
 var wrappedFunction = function() {        
          
 if (before) before.apply(this, arguments);
 result = functionToWrap.apply(this, arguments);
          
 return result;
 }
      
 return wrappedFunction;
}

var beforeFunc = function(){
  // print extra infos before functionToWarp() triggers.
}
```

and my function _printSth to wrap:

```
var Printer = function () {
  this._printSth = function (input) {
    // print something from input...
  }
}
Printer._printSth = wrap(Printer._printSth, beforeFunc);
```

I have tried to wrap `Printer._printSth` by calling

`Printer._printSth = wrap(Printer._printSth, beforeFunc);` or similar codes but failed.
How should I declare my `_printSth()` to be able to be wrapped?

Comment: Regarding the former `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write

```
function Printer() {
  this._printSth = function (input) {
    // print something from input...
  };
  this._printSth = wrap(this._printSth, beforeFunc);
}
```

or

```
function Printer() {
  this._printSth = wrap(function (input) {
    // print something from input...
  }, beforeFunc);
}
```

but that's equivalent to simply writing

```
function Printer() {
  this._printSth = function (input) {
    beforeFunc(input);
    // print something from input...
  };
}
```

Assuming you rather might want to wrap the method on a specific instance, you'd do

```
const p = new Printer();
p._printSth = wrap(p._printSth, beforeFunc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Altering a method is done like that:

```js
Printer.prototype._printSth = wrap(Printer.prototype._printSth, beforeFunc);
```